# Loading Values from Data Space with Z Register?

Tags: assembly, avr, atmega

I'm new to programming in AVR assembly, and I'm having difficulties understanding the following code.

```
.include "m328Pdef.inc" 
main: ldi r22, 0x20
    sts 0x0100, r22
    ldi zh, 0x01
    ldi zl, 0x00
    ldi r20, 0x05
    clr r22
    ld r22, z
    clr r16
    ser r16 
    out DDRB, r16 
    out DDRC, r16 
    out PortB, r30 
    out PortC, r31 
    ret
```

The goal of this program is as follows:

> Write an assembly language program that gets the numbers from the Data
>   Space with memory address 0x0100. Output the lower byte of the result
>   to Port B and the high byte of the result to Port C. (use register z
>   to get number).

Specifically, on line 9 (ld r22, z), is the value that register z points to, which is 32, being loaded into r22, or is the memory address of the pointer itself being loaded into r22?

Also, on line 6 (ldi r20, 0x05), what is the point of this register? It seems like it isn't used anywhere else in the program.

A general explanation of the details of the program would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Specifically, on line 9 (ld r22, z), is the value that register z
>   points to, which is 32, being loaded into r22, or is the memory
>   address of the pointer itself being loaded into r22?

As usual, consult the instruction set reference.
Also, a little thinking should also lead you to the correct answer. Obviously if it were the address, it would just be a simple transfer from `z` to `r22` which makes little sense. Also the goal description clearly says to load the value from data space.

> Also, on line 6 (ldi r20, 0x05), what is the point of this register?
>   It seems like it isn't used anywhere else in the program.

Indeed that's pointless. Just as the `clr 22` before the `ldr r22` or the `clr 16` before `ser 16`. Also the task never says to write into memory first.

Comment: FYI, I did consult the instruction set reference. Thanks for the info, but the downvote was unnecessary.